# Joining 2 queries using UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a better way (more efficient) to write this piece of code?
It works but it looks cluttered and could do with some cleanup.
It basically takes a column from different table and joins it with another, then it checks the last entry and takes the relevant event value. Finally it joins another script where there is no event found for that ID and joins that with the previous script.
I'm sure there's a cleaner way to write this script.

```
SELECT tA.[No_], tA.[Description], tA.[Source], tA.[VGroup], tB.[Event]
FROM [Table1] tA
LEFT JOIN [Table2] tB ON tA.[No_] = tB.[No]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL 
    FROM [Table2] tB
    WHERE tB.[No] = tA.[No_]
)
UNION
SELECT tA.[No_], tA.[Description], tA.[Source], tA.[VGroup], tB.[Event]
FROM [Table1] tA
LEFT JOIN [Table2] tB ON tA.[No_] = tB.[No]
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT MAX(ID)
    FROM [Table2]
    GROUP BY [No]
)
```

Comment: That `LEFT JOIN` and `EXISTS` make no sense. You `LEFT JOIN` to `[Table2]` and then make sure, separately, that there would be no related rows. What are you trying to achieve there.

Comment: Couldn't you just write an inner join?  Those would omit the nulls you are excluding in your not exists.   Right?

Comment: Can you please provide us some sample data and result you want from that

Answer (score 0):

It appears (although it's rather unclear), that you just want to left-join based on the first row per `Table1.No_`.

You can just add a row-number to `Table2`, then left-join and filter on the row-number.

```sql
SELECT
  tA.No_,
  tA.Description,
  tA.Source,
  tA.VGroup,
  tB.Event
FROM Table1 tA
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tB.[No] ORDER BY tB.ID)
    FROM Table2 tB
) tB ON tA.[No_] = tB.[No] AND tB.rn = 1;
```